# Whatsapp sending

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I'm developing an app to send messages in Whatsapp using JS. My app simply call the url below with the correct get parameters :

https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9999999999&text=Mytext

It's working, but everytime i need to send to a new number, if i call this url again, it will reload Whatsapp completely, and it takes a lot of time. Is there a way to do it without reloading the entire Whatsapp app ?

Answer (score -1):

You basically asking for a way to create a WhatsApp spam bot?

Comment: Nope, it's an app to send attached bills to customers of the company i work